# Equals not comparing

Tags: java, android

I have an if statement that works as log in so it compares nick and pass for the user. The problem in question is that the `equals` function is not working or at least not the way I need it to. While debugging the string coming from the input is right ("c" from idTextInput and "1" from PassTextInput) but the comparison returns false every time. Can anyone help me with this?

```
btnJackIn.setOnClickListener(
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public  void onClick(View v){
            EditText idTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtID);
            EditText PassTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);

            if (idTextInput.getText().equals("c") && PassTextInput.getText().equals("1")) {
                Intent characterPage = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainCharacterPage.class);
                characterPage.putExtra("id", idTextInput.getText());
                characterPage.putExtra("pass", PassTextInput.getText());
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(characterPage);

            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: is 'c' typed with a capital 'C' perhaps? I believe it's standard for the first character of an EditText

Comment: Stylized the language and un-indented the code a bit. It is easier to follow especially on mobile devices when it's not indented too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
idTextInput.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("c") && PassTextInput.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")
```

It will also take care of case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

[EditText.getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) returns an `Editable` object, not a String. Try this instead:

```
idTextInput.getText().toString().equals("c") && PassTextInput.getText().toString().equals("1")
```

Comment: this was the problem! thanks, i knew it was simple haha

Answer (score -2):

I once had a huge problem with the && statements, I would try to compare code using it, but it always led me a stray.

Ex;

```
if(!FAnswer3.equals(NotConf && Confirm)){
    System.out.println("\nSorry, that's not a valid command. Try again!");
    continue;
}
```

This code doesn't work because I'm using the wrong comparison thing, (&&)
instead, I'd need to use != because it means "If it's not that either," in this case. Check your code for any changes in your comparing doodads and whathaveyous, (Maybe changing && to == may fix it) and come back again if it still isn't working.

Comment: *I'd need to use != because it means "If it's not that either," in this case.* - that's not true. Also I don't know where you got that && from, that has nothing to do with comparing objects